# How to calculate an inner ellipse points that is always a set distance from an outer ellipse points

Tags: conic-sections, elliptic-functions

I have an Ellipse with known coordinates , I would like to know how I can create an inner ellipse coordinates that are exactly 5 inches **perpendicular** from the outer ellipse points. Please see the drawing at the link  - I have the outer points x,y posted below. Axis Major a 15.75, axis minor b 12.

```
    X     ,  Y
-6.0000,-0.6250
-6.0000,-1.2500
-6.0000,-1.8750
-6.0000,-2.5000
-5.9800,-3.1073
-5.8900,-3.7091
-5.7400,-4.2990
-5.5400,-4.8712
-5.2800,-5.4197
-4.9600,-5.9388
-4.5900,-6.4233
-4.1800,-6.8682
-3.7200,-7.2689
-3.2300,-7.6213
-2.7000,-7.9218
-2.1400,-8.1673
-1.5600,-8.3553
-0.9700,-8.4838
-0.3700,-8.5516
0.3700,-8.5516
0.9700,-8.4838
1.5600,-8.3553
2.1400,-8.1673
2.7000,-7.9218
3.2300,-7.6213
3.7200,-7.2689
4.1800,-6.8682
4.5900,-6.4233
4.9600,-5.9388
5.2800,-5.4197
5.5400,-4.8712
5.7400,-4.2990
5.8900,-3.7091
5.9800,-3.1073
6.0000,-2.5000
6.0000,-1.8750
6.0000,-1.2500
6.0000,-0.6250
```

DRAWING LOCATED HERE : [Inner ellipse generated from points on outer ellipse.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwnfe.png)

ADDED PLOT USING DOUG M formula: Excel Scatter Plot ][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Q1ca.png)
This is somewhat off as the inner Ellipse should match the outer only smaller by 5 ..

```
EXCEL 
cellX =A5-5 * ( (A5/15.75^2) / (SQRT(( (A5^2) / (15.75^4) ) + ( (B5^2) / (12^4) ))))

cellY =B5-5 * ( (B5/12^2) / (SQRT(( (A5^2) / (15.75^4) ) + ( (B5^2) / (12^4) ))))

where:
A = X values.
B = Y values. 
axis major a = 15.75  I changed the semi to 8.5 as it matches the ellipse.
axis minor b = 12 - Semi = 6
```

*EDIT - 4/18/2016*

Attached is a plot in Excel : While these points are 5 inches away from the outer ellipse - they are not perpendicular to the points on the ellipse, I need the perpendicular point -5  from the outer ellipse. Dougs equation does a good job of calculating 5 points away but maybe it will not plot to be an ellipse - which will work for me as long as the points are perpendicular to the outer ellipse.
I am unable to add the additional plot - as I do not have my account on this site combined to the other SO site (same account).

Comment: The inner curve is not an ellipse.  See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1688333/ellipsoid-but-not-quite

Comment: @Ng Chung Tak I confirm: the "eroded curve" of an ellipse is NOT an ellipse.

Comment: Make an account and stick to it... It is at least the third question you ask always with a different profile.

Comment: @N74 - I have an account it shows up on all my posts.

Comment: You have also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4604017/stixo). It would be better you join the two.

Comment: @N74 - how do I join the two ?

Comment: To join the accounts read [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 0):

$\frac {x^2}{a^2} + \frac {y^2}{b^2} = 1$

Suppose we look at

$z = \frac {x^2}{a^2} + \frac {y^2}{b^2} \\
\nabla z = \frac {2x}{a^2}, \frac {2y}{b^2} $

This vector is perpendicular to the elipse.

if $(x,y)$ is on your elipse, then $(x,y) - 5\dfrac{(\frac {x}{a^2},\frac {y}{b^2})}{\sqrt{\frac {x^2}{a^4}+\frac {y^2}{b^4}}}$ is on the curve you are looking for.

Comment: does this also work if this is considered a super ellipse ? The math seems straight forward . I will take this and try to apply it. I am not sure how to apply the equation - given the comma in the numerator. Is there a link that would explain this formula - how to apply it ?

Comment: In the equation at the commas am I really just substituting which to solve first?

Comment: the comma separates the x coordinate from the y coordinate.

Comment: @ Doug M - I understand the separation but I guess I do not understand the solving of the problem  for example if  I have 2 values x,y 1,2  placing in 1/a^2 and using that as my numerator to solve for my x point (of course leaving the denominator with both x and y values. Then for y substitute the 2 in for y  and my numerator would be made up of only the y/b^2 component ?

Comment: I plotted the points in Excel and attached the snapshot , I listed the formula in the problem edit. The points are close but do not follow the outer as I should have the outer ellipse duplicated only smaller (5 points). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: a and b are the lengths of the semi-major axis and semi-minor axis.

Comment: The plot is 5  away but the points are not perpendicular with the ellipse points - perhaps the actual result will not be an ellipse  but may look more like a bulb thermometer in the end. Perhaps I need to post the question differently. BTW: thanks for the formula - I have learned something.